# Seq of observable to observable

Tags: scala, observable, mongo-scala-driver

I use mongo-scala-driver 1.0.1 that return Observable[Completed] after **insertMany**.

I put many documents in cycle and I need to do some action after all of it already inserted.

I can use observable.toFuture to get Seq[Future[Completed]] and then Future.sequence(...) to handle future.

But is it possible to transform `Seq[Observable[Completed]]` to `Observable[...]` in Scala? Or there is a better way to handle it?

mongo-scala-driver has it's own Observable trait org.mongodb.scala.Observable

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to flatten `List` of `Observable`s into single `Observable`.

```
List(
  Observable.interval(200 millis),
  Observable.interval(400 millis),
  Observable.interval(800 millis)
).toObservable.flatten.take(12).toBlocking.foreach(println(_))
```

You can find this and many more examples here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/0.x/examples/src/test/scala/examples/RxScalaDemo.scala

### Edit

Here is what should work with mongo api, although I didn't test it.

```
val observables: Seq[Observable[Int]] = ???
val result: Observable[Int] = Observable(observables).flatMap(identity)
```

Comment: Thanks. But mongo-scala-driver has it's own Observable (org.mongodb.scala.Observable) and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try my edit. It should just merge all given observables.